# How to keep observing an object until onError() / unsubscribing

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

I need to observe a list of objects and emit an event as soon as there is a new object in the list. Like a client - server application where the client adds content to the list and the server emits the newly added content to all the clients registered in the server.

So far, my observable only emits one item and nothing more after it. In other words, when a new object is added in to the list there is an event but when a second (or 3rd, 4th, 5th...) object is added there is no event.

I need it to keep emiting items as soon as there are new objects in the list.

This is my code, where `MyList` is let's say my own implementation of `List` (not relevant to my question). I want the emitted event to be the newly added object to `MyList`.

```
private void onClickMethod() {
    MyList myList = populateMyList();

    onNexAction = new Action1<MyList>() {
        @Override
        public void call(MyList myList) {
            System.out.println("call()");
            TheObject theObject = myList.getNext();
            System.out.println("New Event: " + theObject.getData());
        }
    };

    myObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<MyList>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super MyList> t) {
            t.onNext(myList);
        }
    });

    myObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(onNexAction);
}
```

The code above will only emit the first added object. But if I place a while cycle inside call() it will be emitting all the events, like I want. But I feel like not the appropriate way to do what I want. I feel like I'm more like polling rather than async.

Here is the exact same code but with the while cycle:

```
private void onClickMethod() {
    MyList myList = populateMyList();

    onNexAction = new Action1<MyList>() {
        @Override
        public void call(MyList myList) {
            System.out.println("call()");
            while (myList.size() > 0) { // The while cycle
                TheObject theObject = myList.getNext();
                System.out.println("New Event: " + theObject.getData());
            }
        }
    };

    myObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<MyList>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super MyList> t) {
            t.onNext(myList);
        }
    });

    myObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(onNexAction);
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? How can I keep my observable emitting a new event as soon as there is a new object in MyList?

***EDIT:***

As suggested by Tassos Bassoukos, I applied the `distinct()` operator like this:

```
myObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).distinct().subscribe(onNexAction);
```

But it doesn't solve my problem. Only the first added object is emitted.

Comment: Why can't you use Observable::distinct for this task?

Comment: I've edited my question where I added `distinct()` operator as you suggested but to no help. It still stops emitting events after the first added object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical case for `PublishSubject`:

```
class MyList<T> {
    final PublishSubject<T> onAdded = PublishSubject.create();
    void add(T value) {
        // add internally
        onAdded.onNext(value);
    }
    Observable<T> onAdded() {
        return onAdded;
    }
}

MyList<Integer> list = populate();

Subscription s = list.onAdded()
    .subscribe(v -> System.out.println("Added: " + v));

list.add(1);  // prints "Added: 1"
list.add(2);  // prints "Added: 2"
list.add(3);  // prints "Added: 3"

s.unsubscribe(); // not interested anymore

list.add(4);  // doesn't print anything
list.add(5);  // doesn't print anything
```

Comment: This solved my problem, this is it. Thanks! PS; You forgot to close a `)` on your code - on the `System.out.println("Added: " + v);` it should be `("Added: " + v));`

Comment: Another detail is: `onAdded()` has to return a `PublishSubject` object. Not an `Observable` as in your code, otherwise the code does not compile.

Comment: Thanks for ). It compiles for me, did you accidentally import `java.util.Observable` instead of `rx.Observable`?

Comment: You are correct. My IDE imported the wrong `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, when an user click (on something), the `onClickMethod` is called.

this method will create an object `myList` and you'll build an item that will emit this object. Then you'll consume this object.

In fact, you'll just emit your list once, that's why you're only notify once (on one click)

To achieve what you're looking for, a possible way is to emit each item of your list when you add one.

```
private void onClickMethod() {
     MyList myList = populateMyList();

     myObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
               int currentSize = myList.size();
               while(myList.size() != currentSize) {
                    subscriber.onNext(myList.getNext());
                    currentSize = myList.size();
               }
               subscriber.onCompleted();
     });

   myObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

}

Please note that this code is **NOT** performant as it will loop over `myList.size()` and you may encounter issue if someone add/remove items during the loop code.

A better approach would be to be notified when a new item is added in `myList`, then emit this new item.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason you are not getting more than one value from your observable is that the method that you pass to `Observable.create` is only called *once*, and that occurs when it is first subscribed to. If you want to just hook up your list as an observable the easiest way is to make `MyList` class implement `Iterable` and you can directly use `from` instead

```
private void onClickMethod() {
 MyList myList = populateMyList();
 Observable.from(myList)
           .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
           .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item));

}
```